# PHP Code on Windows 2016 Server - JSON Doesn't Seem to Be Running (IIS)

Tags: php, json, windows, iis

So, a little background.... There's a lot here, but I don't know how much of it could be important for finding a solution, so I'm putting all of it here.

I work on a small campus, and the library here wants to implement an inventory tool that's available through Github. The tool uses an API for the library system so that whenever you scan a barcode into the webpage, it will go into the catalog and retrieve the bibliographic information and allow users to note if there are any issues with the item. Then, when they're finished, they click on a link and it will export the data to a Google Sheets document that the librarians can use to fix the issues.

The developer included a Docker installation of the app, and when we set it up and run it through Docker, everything works fine. The Docker installation appears to mimic a Linux environment, but based on what little I know about PHP, it shouldn't make a difference in how the site works if it's in Linux or Windows. I've set it up on our only server running PHP (Windows Server 2016), and the page loads and exports just fine, but we have a problem when we try to retrieve the bibliographic data. The API appears to be fine (see: Docker installation), but there's an error in the console that I can't seem to fix:

```
Uncaught TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got null
```

(Note: This error doesn't occur on the page; it adds the barcode just fine, but nothing else loads into the page from the API. We only see that error in the console.)

This is the code it's referencing on that error:

```
function parseResponse(barcode, json) {
  var resdata = {}
  if ('errorsExist' in json) {
  ...
```

It's the third line that's throwing the error, and based on the error message, the right side is null, which, to me, suggests that json isn't running.

I researched that problem and discovered I needed to add the json MIME type to IIS on the server. I checked, and it was already there. Further research suggested I needed to add a script map to Handler Mappings, and when I went to do that, I found that asp.dll didn't exist on the server (irrespective of the fact that we have another PHP site on there that appears to be running). More research showed that I had to add ASP.NET through Server Manager, and when I did that, I was able to locate and add asp.dll to get the script map to work.

The thing is, it's still not working. I still get that error message, and I can't find anything else to try when I search Google. At one point, I switched the MIME type from application/json to text/json, since I found something from an older (6+ years) article suggesting to do so, but no luck. I'm out of ideas, and I'm hoping someone with more experience can point me in the right direction. I feel like I'm **so close** to getting this, but it's beyond my experience to solve it.

So. Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I forgot to note ... the original developer no longer has access to the library system for which the tool was developed, and he appears to no longer be supporting it.

Comment: Does it work properly locally? or does this error only appear in Windows Server?

Comment: Do you mean localhost? I can't even get that page to load (this server is running three different sites, using two different hosts). Or is there something else you mean? Sorry, my expertise isn't web design, so a lot of this stuff is very new to me.

Comment: I mean that this problem will only appear when it is released in iis? Can you use VS to run normally?